# pie plot in matplotlib in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a pie chart from a `.txt` file with data-set looks like:

```
asp: 2.11
glu: 1.11
arg: 0.99
his: 5.11
acid: 11.1
base: 2.11
```

now,
1) I want to plot a pie chart with first 4 entries, with proper labeling.
2) and then another pie plot using last 2 entries.

I was trying with this following code but I am getting errors. My code is:

```
from pylab import *
inp = open('c:/users/rox/desktop/xx.txt','r').read().strip().replace(': ',' ').split('\n')
for line in map(str.split,inp):
    x = line[0]
    z = line[1]
    fracs = [x]
    labels = [z]
    pie(fracs,labels=labels,explode=None,autopct='%1.1f%%,shadow=False)
    show()
```

but this code is generating an error report: Could not convert string to float...

and do I need to use `tempfile`  to plot first 4 entries present in the `.txt` file.

if I want to plot pie chart using last two line of data set, then could it be done using `slicing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** make input more general, so multiple plots can be read from same file:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_data(f, num_lines=1, split_on=':'):
    lines = (f.next() for i in range(num_lines))
    pieces = (line.split(split_on) for line in lines)
    data = ((a,float(b)) for a,b in pieces)
    return zip(*data)

with open("xx.txt") as inf:
    amino_names, amino_values = read_data(inf, 4)
    ph_names, ph_values = read_data(inf, 2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,1))
p1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
p1.pie(amino_values, labels=amino_names)
p2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
p2.pie(ph_values, labels=ph_names)
fig.show()
```

results in

[image]

Comment: problem in last line. It raises error : 'tuple' object has no attribute 'show'. and could be corrected if use: plt.show() in next line.

Comment: @Ovisek: which version Python, matplotlib, OS? Works for me as-is with Windows 7 64-bit, Python 2.7.2, matplotlib 1.1.0

Comment: okey it's fine but for plotting pie with last 2 entries how do i skip